# Notation: what does $[D:F]$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, extension-field

This is a problem given in the exercise of my text book(Chapter: Algebraic Extension of Fields) But I don't understand the question properly.

> Let $D$ be an integral domain and $F$ be a field in $D$ such that $[D:F]<∞$. Prove, $D$ is a field.

If $D$ is not a field then what does $[D:F]$ denote? I know if $E$ is an extension field over a field $F$, then $[E:F]$ denotes the order of $E$ over $F$.

Can anybody clear my queries? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: It is the dimension of $D$ as an $F$-vector space.

Comment: Hello: it is best to make the title your actual question, when possible. In this case, you made your title a highly duplicated question on this site, and so it might have been snapped shut by someone not realizing what your real question is.

Comment: Mea culpa. I accidentally obliterated the question when I changed the title. I thought I had seen the question in the body too (intended to be in the colored box) but it looks like it was not there. It looks like the problem came from page 27 or so.

Answer (score 3):

For a field extension $F\subset E$, $[E:F]$ denotes the dimension of $E$ as an $F$ vector space. I think it is also written as $|E:F|$ sometimes as well.

From page 1 of your book:

[image]

I think it is reasonable to assume that it means the same thing if $E$ is replaced with any $F$ algebra.

Comment: But the question was explicitly for the case wher $D$ is _not_ a field. I suppose one could still use the notation $[V:k]$ for the dimension of an arbitrary $k$-vector space $V$, but that seems to be rather less common.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right.  More than one confusion borne out of a question originally split between title and body.